# Forward class declaration with template using typename

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following scenario: -

```
template<typename Derived, typename ValType>
class foo
{
public:
    template<typename R>
    bar<typename std::vector<R>::const_iterator> select()
    {
        std::vector<R> translation;

        return bar<typename std::vector<R>::const_iterator>(std::move(translation));
    }
};

template<typename T>
class bar
    : public foo<bar<T>, typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type>
{
public:
    bar(std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type>&& vec)
    {

    }
};
```

It's basically a little proof of concept I'm playing with  using CRTP with foo being a mixin.

The problem is that I believe I should be using a forward declaration however I have tried the following: -

```
class bar; // I didn't expect this to work
```

however I did expect this to work: -

```
template<typename R>
class bar;
```

which compiles fine until I actually call select()

```
std::vector<int> enumerable_vector;
enumerable_vector.push_back(1);
enumerable_vector.push_back(2);

bar<typename std::vector<int>::const_iterator> baz(std::move(enumerable_vector));
baz.select<std::string>();
```

which results in the following error: -

> Error error C2027: use of undefined type
>   'foo::bar'

Any assistance would be appreciate, thanks!

Comment: It works fine with GCC and [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5244a59ca673d26c) given the forward declaration that you expected to work.

Comment: @Daniel Frey Are you calling select() on baz?

Comment: Yes, just click the link in my comment.

Comment: I was putting the forward class declaration inside foo. I figured it would only apply locally in that case but the answer below resolves the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Error error C2027: use of undefined type 'foo::bar'

The error message seems to indicate that you forward declared a nested type `bar` within `foo`. You need to forward declare the correct type (move the declaration of `bar` to namespace level just over the definition of `foo`)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This answer is incorrect. `bar` need not be complete when `select` is *defined*, it must be complete when `select` is *instantiated*. Moving the definition of `select` out-of-line after the class specifier for `bar` is not necessary.

---

The problem is that your definition of `select` inside the class specifier for `foo` requires `bar` to be complete. If you forward declare `bar` and only *declare* `select` in the class specifier, you can move the definition of `select` out-of-line to where `bar` is complete. [It then compiles fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4e27b83d8f8a266):

```
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template<typename T> class bar;

template<typename Derived, typename ValType>
class foo
{
public:
    template<typename R>
    bar<typename std::vector<R>::const_iterator> select();
};

template<typename T>
class bar
    : public foo<bar<T>, typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type>
{
public:
    bar(std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type>&& vec)
    {

    }
};

template<typename Derived, typename ValType>
template<typename R>
bar<typename std::vector<R>::const_iterator> foo<Derived, ValType>::select()
{
    std::vector<R> translation;
    return bar<typename std::vector<R>::const_iterator>(std::move(translation));
}
```

Comment: Great answer but the other answer solved it for me as it was a d'oh moment that made me realise my mistake as soon as he posted.

Comment: @chrisw69: It is very valuable to learn to read error messages, and to then *read* the error messages :)